# How to change the year of your birthday to current year in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to change the year of your birthday to current year in vb.net?

example my birthday is 2/14/1990 --> 2/14/2013

but the day you change is not 2/14 like you change it to the date of 2/20 so its not equal to the present day.

How can i change my birthday year to current year?

Comment: If your question is about how to find your birthday this year, it will always be `2/14`. The only way that would change is if you were born on `2/29` in a leap year. In other words, if your birthday is 2/14/1990, and you want to find your 30th birthday, it would be `2/14` of `1990 + 30`, and `1990 + 30 = 2020`, so your  30th birthday would be `2/14/2020`.

Comment: You need to be going at least 88 mph for that to work. (In seriousness, it's not clear at all what you're really asking).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already got it. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this using the [`AddYears`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method of the Date object

```
Dim myBirthday As Date = Date.Parse("2/14/1990")
myBirthday = myBirthday.AddYears(23)
```

Answer (score 0):

My dos centavos

```
    'what about leap years
    Dim myBirthday As DateTime = #2/29/2000#

    'the following doesn't work 
    ' Dim myBirthdayThisYear As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, myBirthday.Month, myBirthday.Day)

    'this works
    Dim myBirthdayThisYear As DateTime = DateSerial(DateTime.Now.Year, myBirthday.Month, myBirthday.Day)
```